# Find values of $a$ for which $|x-a|=(x-2)^2$

Tags: calculus

Find all values of $a$ for which $|x-a|=(x-2)^2$.

This is a calculus question and I'm told I'm suppose to use the derivative. But the thing is that the absolute value function on the left side looks nothing alike to the parabola function on the right, so how could there be any real number $a$ where this is true?

Comment: Have you tried graphing examples?

Comment: No matter the $a$, there is at least one $x$ that is a solution. I think the issue is the problem statement, not your understanding.

Comment: There's no point in looking for equivalence, the graphs must intersect at some point. As for an example, put $a=2$, then $x=3$ is a solution.

Comment: There does not exist any value of $a$ such that $|x-a|=(x-2)^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. The equation $|x-a|=(x-2)^2$ has at the most 4 solutions, no more.

Comment: Angelo can you explain why there are at most $4$ solutions?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Click Here]

I agree with you, a linear can't be a parabola, though it can have 1 or 2 solutions for various values of "a"!! I have tried to show it through the image!!

Comment: **Pro-tip:** You can use graphing calculators like desmos and geogebra

Comment: There can also be $3$ or $4$ solutions for some values of $a$, but there is never only one solution.